# Using case max date() does not return all parent rows

Tags: sql-server-2008

Hi The following query does not return all projects and all stores. It shows only a store which has at least one status date filled.

How can I get all the projects from projects table and all stores from stores table and also show the status date for the stores (wherever it is filled).

```
SELECT
    ProjectName,Store,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Activity = 'Visited' THEN Date ELSE NULL END) AS Visited,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Activity = 'NotVisited' THEN Date ELSE NULL END) AS NotVisited,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Activity = 'Finished' THEN Date ELSE NULL END) AS Finished
FROM Table1 T
INNER JOIN Project P
ON T.ProjectID = P.ProjectID
INNER JOIN Store S
ON T.StoreID = S.StoreID
INNER JOIN Activity A
ON T.ActivityID = A.ActivityID
GROUP BY ProjectName,Store
```

Comment: Please format your code as code.

Comment: Its really good to have few sample data for above mentioned tables.